# Как менять пропы vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

Есть страница в которой по клику вызывается модальное окно (при клике меняется флаг).
Родительский компонент:

```
  <transfer-modal-accept :is-modal-show="isModalShow" v- 
  if="isModalShow" />
  ...
  const isModalShow = ref(false)
```

Использую элементовский компонент модалки, в котором v-model отвечает за отображение окна:

```
<template>
    <el-dialog v-model="props.isModalShow">
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
      type Props = {
        isModalShow: boolean
      }

      const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {})
</script>
```

Получаю "Unexpected mutation of props

Answer (score 0):

Пропы нельзя изменять, они только для чтения

Получай значения через проп, и задавай его самим данным твоего компонента

Не знаю как будет на TS, но на JS:

```
props: {
    isModalShow: {
        required: true,
        type: boolean,
        default: false,
    }
}

data() {
    return {
        isShow: this.isModalShow,
    }
}
```

Comment: Если надо, чтобы значение пропа всё таки изменилось, и родительский компонент это увидел, то испольуй emit для этого и перехватывай в родителе